# How to explain to English speakers how to pronounce a pure Spanish E as in *meta*

Tags: pronunciación, vocales

*Tell me if you want me to post this at ELU -- but please don't downvote me into oblivion.  I'm happy to delete here and repost there if need be.*

I thought I could explain to English speakers how to pronounce the pure E of Spanish as in *meta* by referencing the Canadian "eh," but it turns out that doesn't work because apparently the Canadian "eh" is a diphthong.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/363302/112436.

So how do others explain this in writing?  (If I'm explaining live, I can just demonstrate, obviously.)

Comment: I don't think it'd be for ELU, but rather the new Language Learning SE.

Comment: "Like the *e* in *get*"? Granted, this one is lax not tense, but that's not a problem in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

There are several words in the English language that sound "LIKE" the E in the Spanish language:

> **e**phemeral, end**ea**vor, **e**nergy, **E**verest.

That's generally the sound of the vowel.

Another way to explain this is by using the [short "e"](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/themes/letters/shorte.shtml) sound

> > The words are leg, ten, hen, web, lemon, pen, vest, nest, jet, net. Or go to the answers. Circle Words that have a Short 'E' Sound. Circle 10 words that have a short E sound. The words are ten, pen, jet, web, nest, net, pencil, envelope, leg, vest.

Comment: Mike, please see clarified question. // Suggest you remove the part about the syllables from this particular answer since it has nothing to do with what I was asking.  (But if we don't already have a Q and A about that, maybe it would make a good separate question.)

Comment: Will do, 
I wasn't really sure what the OP was requesting